# JS file not working in laravel

Tags: laravel

So basically I have this code where I click on the image, it gets html file and should display it on the same page. It does display it but on another page, my guess is that it's not actually loading js file for some reason. Anyone can help?

View:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Best programmer ever')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/template.js')}}" rel="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
@section('content')
@endsection
        @section('template')
        <!--     @foreach ($templates as $template)
           {{$template->image}}
            {{$template->file}}
        @endforeach
        -->
        <div class= "template_class">
          <a class="content-link" href="templates/template1.html"> 
        <img id = "image" src="{{ asset($template->image )}}"/>
  </a>
</div>
        @show
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
   $('.content-link').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $('.content').load(this.href)
                    .fail(function()( alert('Oops...something went wrong')));

   });
});
alert("hello");
```

It doesn't even show alert so that's why I think it is not loading it.

Comment: Does your js file shows up in the network tab of chrome tools?

Answer (score 1):

The `<script>` tags are out of the `@section` sections.

Try changing it like this:

```
@section('content')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{asset('/js/template.js')}}" rel="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
@endsection
```

If it doesn't work, check if the JS files are really included in your browser. (Open the Chrome Dev Tools and check the DOM)

Comment: seems like it's working however I am getting: template.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load(...).fail is not a function

Comment: Seems like it's a jQuery error. I don't think that you can use the `fail()` method after `load()`. [$.load Doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: however if I remove fail() it doesn't work at all, with it at least it displays the page but unfortunately on another page and I want it on the same one